# Static IP - Destination Host Unreachable

Tags: networking, internet, ubuntu-20.04, drac, netplan

I'm a newbie to system administration. I've installed remotely a Dell server using iDRAC interface. Server's ip is 200.159.243.146 and everything is fine with it.

Using this interface I've installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 without problem. However, from this system I do not have internet access. This is the result of the command 'ip addr':

[image]

This is the content of Netplan configuration file:

[image]

As you can see, iDRAC interface has the ip 200.159.243.146 while the ethernet has the ip 200.159.243.147. Outside from this network I can ping the first ip but I can't ping the second one.

Does anybody has a hint of what's going wrong?

Comment: Exactly what model of Dell server is it? Is your iDRAC NIC shared?

Comment: Can you ping your GW and the DNS server ? and let us know the result.

Comment: If there are problems with the ping to the gateway, it is wise to check ARP table (`ip neigh show`).

Comment: Check the VM network settings to see if you actually allocated the NIC properly (with host-like address).

Comment: The server is a PowerEdge T140. About NIC, I don't know exactly what it means, but it is Dedicated. I can't ping both GW and DNS. It gives "Destination Host Unreachable". The command "ip neigh show" returns this message: "200.159.243.1 dev eno1 INCOMPLETE". How do I check VM network settings?

Comment: Dear, thank all of you for the replies but the problem was solved. I was checking some basic stuff and I've discovered someone tripped over the network cable (I'm working remotely so it's hard to figure out such things). iDRAC has another cable which is fine. What should I do with the question? Should I ask for closing it?